# Design guidance for methods returning objects in java / can I use exceptions?

Tags: java

If I have a method say `getNextWidget()` that returns a widget, what is the proper design for such a method if I need to check the size of say, the factory that makes the widget and only return a widget if there are widgets in the factory?  Is there a way to throw an exception for a method that is not `void`?

Comment: Yes absolutely, and it's done all the time. Simply throw the exception, and if it's a checked exception, make sure the method indicates that this is possibly thrown.

Comment: Yes, in fact any method can throw an exception. It's upto you to decide when and what exception to throw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common pattern is to return `null` when there is no more widget to be had. This works very well if the method otherwise never returns `null`.

Another common pattern is to throw an Exception. But then you should have a `hasMoreWidgets()` method, too. In the normal flow of operation (for example retrieving all widgets until none are left), the program should not trigger exceptions.

Either way, if there may be more widgets, but there was some problem accessing the factory, so that you cannot be sure, you should throw an Exception (because this would be a real error condition).

Comment: Agree, and the key is to document explicitly what is happening, especially if the method is public. Document both the return type, what will happen in the edge cases, and the intent of all this.